# Apply multiple if/else statement to groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a very large DataFrame according to below:

```
id  amt date
1   0   2010-02-01
1   0   2012-05-12
1   0   2016-08-09
1   20  1970-01-01
2   0   2016-03-21
2   0   2017-11-10
2   0   2012-09-01
2   0   2016-04-15
```

What I want is to reduce it to one row per id according to following logic:

1. For a given ID-group: if amt > 0 and date == 1970-01-01 then output row.
2. For a given ID-group: if amt == 0 for all id rows, output max date for id

I want appearance according to below.

```
id  amt date
1   20  1970-01-01
2   0   2017-11-10
```

I have actually solved it through sort and grouping by ID and then taking last(). However, my issue came when I tried to write a function which operates on each separate groupby object and applies the logic i have in point 1 and point 2 above (if/else-style). Can someone help me with this?

Code for DataFrame is below - and please note, the data is large so quick execution is helpful.

Many thanks,

/Swepab

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
              ,'amt' : [0, 0, 0, 20, 0 ,0, 0, 0]
              ,'date' : ['2010-02-01', '2012-05-12','2016-08-09'
                       ,'1970-01-01','2016-03-21','2017-11-10'
                       ,'2012-09-01','2016-04-15']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df = df[['id', 'amt', 'date']]
```

Comment: In your condition 1, you have 1970-01-01 as date. Is that a condition to check or is that the date you want when 'amt > 0'?

Comment: Its supposed to be checked, i.e. logical true of "amt > 0  and date == '1970-01-01" then output. I tried to write a function to handle this but failed, hence my question on how to write one and apply on groupby object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom function which you can apply on individual groups

```
def custom_fx(df):
if df.amt.sum() == 0:
    max_date = df.date.max()
    return df.loc[df.date==max_date,:]
elif df.amt.sum() != 0 :
     return df[df.date.isin(["1970-01-01"])]

for groups,data in df.groupby("id"):
    print(custom_fx(data))
```

OUTPUT:

```
     amt       date       id
 3   20       1970-01-01   1
     amt       date       id
 5    0       2017-11-10   2
```

Comment: I can run that function through "groupby('id').apply(custom_fx)" and it works well. It is a little bit slower than my own solution but it gives way for flexibility in the logic you written, and it also serves as a good example. Im accepting it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do not think we need `groupby` here , by using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['amt','date']).drop_duplicates('id',keep='last')
Out[1139]: 
   id  amt       date
5   2    0 2017-11-10
3   1   20 1970-01-01
```

Comment: More or less like my own solution with sort + groupby id + last(). Reason I asked question is to learn how to solve it with a function used on groupby('id').apply(function_for_select). You know what I mean?